# mysqld.exe - application error on Laragon start

Tags: mysql, laragon

I just installed Laragon but when it wants to start its services, it "freezes" when mySQL have to be launched, then shows me that message :

```
mysqld.exe - Application Error
This application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application.
```

After that, Laragon's window writes "initialize data..." then does not change until I stop all services.

I wanted to check the log files but... zero log. So impossible to have some details...

I've tried to uninstall and reinstall.
I've tried another version of mySQL.

None of them works. WAMP is also installed on my computer, but I don't really want to uninstall it (and I don't think that's problem since I have both at work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think MySQL 5.7 is not compatible with your OS.

You can try two options:

1. Copy your MySQL in WAMP to laragon\bin\mysql\
2. Use MariaDB

Comment: A bit late, but your second solution worked as hell. Thx